# run python command from C code with specific encoding

Tags: python, c, encoding, python-3.x, embed

`int PyRun_SimpleString(const char *command)`
  is the function which can run a command of Python.

I call this function in my program, but how can I specify the encoding of the `command` argument. I found that Python 3 seems to use UTF-8 as the default encoding when I run a command. Can I change this encoding in the C level API? ...or with an extra parameter when call `PyRun_SimpleString`-like function?

Answer (score 3):

You can prepend one of the "magic comments" described in [PEP 263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) to your command:

```
char buf[1024];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "-*- coding: %s -*-\n", yourEncoding);
strncat(buf, yourCommand, sizeof(buf) - strlen(buf) - 1);
PyRun_SimpleString(buf);
```

Comment: But i think this is a little inconvenient , right? And i just want a way to specific the encoding at one time and i can use it for ever, is there this kind of function?